# How to do bulk insert in mybatis where we want to iterate over List of Map in Oracle

Tags: java, list, foreach, hashmap, mybatis

I am using INSERT statement with SELECT UNION ALL for bulk insert in Orcle MyBatis.
My issue is I want to make this query as runtime query where column name and data to be inserted is taken from List.
I tried using the below nested for-each but no luck.

```
<insert id="insertData" parameterType="map">
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, AGE, ADDREESS)
<foreach collection="emplist" index="index" item="element" separator="UNION ALL">
  SELECT 
   <foreach collection="element" index="key" item="value">
     #{value}
   </foreach>
  FROM DUAL
</foreach>
</insert>
```

Parameter passed is
emplist = [{name="abc",age=12,address=xyz"},
{name="efg",age=19,address=pqr"}];

#{value} is giving me null

Comment: The `index` attribute should populate the key of the map. Try displaying it to make sure you are getting the correct values for it. Also make sure the map is iterated in the correct order you want (a TreeMap, a LinkedHashMap, but not a HashMap).

Comment: Also, you have two options for INSERTs: 1) Parameterized (highly controlled) ones, or 2) Plain text ones (vulnerable to SQL Injection) using Dynamic SQL. For an insert with dynamic number of columns and dynamic types, I think you'll be better off using the second option, since it's fully flexible.

Answer (score 0):

As `emplist` is a `List` of `Map`s, you can just reference each value in the `Map` by its key.

```xml
<insert id="insertData">
  INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, AGE, ADDREESS)
  <foreach item="x" collection="emplist" separator="UNION ALL">
    SELECT #{x.name}, #{x.age}, #{x.address} FROM DUAL
  </foreach>
</insert>
```

Comment: My use case is these keys like name, age are not fixed those are also variable. We need to fetch it at the run time.

Comment: Then please update the question so that we can understand your requirement accurately. You should add sample parameters with different keys and the expected final SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone.
Finally I got the way to iterate List of Map.

```
<insert id="insertData">
  INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (NAME, AGE, ADDREESS)
  <foreach item="item" collection="emplist" separator="UNION ALL">
   SELECT
    <foreach item="element" collection="item" seperator=",">
       <if test="element!=null">#{element}</if>
       <if test="element==null">null</if>
    </foreach>
   FROM DUAL
  </foreach>
</insert>
```